# isolating different names from a string with the same structure

Tags: python, string, extract

In my program I get the following string with group names returned:

```
[<TdmsGroup with path /'Current 1'>, <TdmsGroup with path /'Break Torque'>]
```

Sometimes even more group names:

```
[<TdmsGroup with path /'Current 1'>, <TdmsGroup with path /'Break Torque'>], <TdmsGroup with path /'Pressure'>]
```

So I have the names of all the groups, but they are separated by commas and nested in the text.

How do I get all the words from the string that are between the quotes?

I would like to have the following group names written from the above string into a dataframe, for example:

- **Current 1**
- **Break Torque**
- **Pressure**

Does anyone have an idea how?

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? A [mcve] with code will help us understand how best to help you

Answer (score 0):

Normally i would post an minimal example, but i have no idea to solve that problem.
For example i found something to extract one group:

```
>>> s = 'lalalala1234lulululu'
>>> start = s.find('lalalala1') + 3
>>> end = s.find('lulululu', start)
>>> s[start:end]
```

but the problem is, that i have more then one group in the string, so i also have to separate them from each other.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression to extract the text present between `'`.

```
import re

a = ["<TdmsGroup with path /'Current 1'>", "<TdmsGroup with path /'Break Torque'>", "<TdmsGroup with path /'Pressure'>"]

regex = re.compile(r"(?<=')[^']+(?=')")
output = []
for i in a:
    output.extend(regex.findall(i))
print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
['Current 1', 'Break Torque', 'Pressure']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer, i tried it but i get the following output:

```
['Current 1', '>, <TdmsGroup with path /', 'Break Torque']
```

I Think the Reason ist, because your String looks like:

```
"<TdmsGroup with path /'Current 1'>", "<TdmsGroup with path /'Break Torque'>", "<TdmsGroup with path /'Pressure'>"
```

And my one like:

```
[<TdmsGroup with path /'Current 1'>, <TdmsGroup with path /'Break Torque'>]
```

So, the parts between the commas are not separated by ""

the entire string comes out raw as shown above

I also don't understand exactly the code, so how exactly the code recognizes the parts. Can you explain me vllt. still ungfähr.
Especially the following part:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=')[^']+(?=')")
```

Between the characters I can't find the characters again that are found in my string, so what exactly does this line do?